# Android: Change button text after MediaPlayer audio ends

Tags: java, android

So I'm following Big Nerd Ranch's Android Programming book and I have an audio file playing through MediaPLayer. I also have a button that both plays and pauses the audio. If you press the play button to play the audio the text on the button changes to "pause". The problems is after the audio ends the button still says "pause" so the user has to press the button twice to play the audio again. How would I get the button to change its text to "play right after the audio ends"

Here's my code minus the layout xml for the buttons

Fragment class:

```java
public class HelloMoonFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mPlayButton;
    private Button mStopButton;

    private AudioPlayer mPlayer = new AudioPlayer();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, parent, false);

        mPlayButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_playButton);
        mPlayButton.setText("Play");
        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mPlayButton.getText().equals("Play")) {
                    mPlayButton.setText("Pause");
                    mPlayer.play(getActivity());
                }
                else if(mPlayButton.getText().equals("Pause")){
                    mPlayButton.setText("Play");
                    mPlayer.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        mStopButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_stopButton);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               mPlayer.stop();
               mPlayButton.setText("Play");
           }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

MediaPlayer class:

```java
package com.bignerdranch.android.hellomoon;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class AudioPlayer {

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private boolean mCompleted =  false;

    public void stop() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    public void play(Context c) {

        if(mPlayer == null) {
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.one_small_step);

            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    stop();
                    mCompleted = true;
                }
            });
        }
            mPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        if(mPlayer != null) mPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my honest opinion, I think the `AudioPlayer` class is not necessary and it seems redundant. If however you think it is needed (i.e. you will add other methods/features to the class to make it more specific than the `MediaPlayer`) then please explain why in your question and I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `MediaPlayer` class directly on the activity, then you can use its `OnCompletionListener` to detect if the media stops playing. inside this `OnCompletionListener` you can switch your button's text from "Pause" to "Play" like so:

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mPlayButton.setText("Play");
    }
});
```

I integrated your AudioPlayer to the fragment so that it would look like:

```
public class HelloMoonFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mPlayButton;
    private Button mStopButton;

    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private boolean mCompleted =  false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello_moon, parent, false);

        mPlayButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_playButton);
        mPlayButton.setText("Play");

        mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mPlayer == null) {
                    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.one_small_step);
                    mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            stopMediaPlayer();
                            mPlayButton.setText("Play");
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(mPlayButton.getText().equals("Play")) {
                    mPlayButton.setText("Pause");
                    mPlayer.start();
                }
                else if(mPlayButton.getText().equals("Pause")){
                    mPlayButton.setText("Play");
                    mPlayer.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        mStopButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.hellomoon_stopButton);
        mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
                stopMediaPlayer();
                mPlayButton.setText("Play");
           }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopMediaPlayer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    public void stopMediaPlayer() {
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```