# How to define a listener on audio file completion in Codename One?

Tags: audio, codenameone

My app features the same button to play and stop an audio file. My problem deals with detecting when the audio file has completed and has been already described [for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520608/android-change-button-text-after-mediaplayer-audio-ends).

I use the following code to play the audio file :

```
Media audio = MediaManager.createMedia(audioPath, false);            
audio.play();
```

But I can't find any method that looks like `setOnCompletionListener` in the Media class, to tell if the end of the audio file has been reached. The only workaround that came to my mind was to use a timer that triggers a task that checks if `audio.getTime() == audio.getDuration()` every now and then.

Is there anything better ?

Any hint appreciated,

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Media audio = MediaManager.createMedia(audioPath, false, () -> runOnComplete());            
audio.play();
```

Comment: Oh I missed this constructor! Thanks @Shai that's working perfectly and way shorter than the TimerTask!