# How do you set media.IsPlaying() to false?

Tags: android, media

Essentially a sound plays on a button click. I'm trying to change the image of the button when the sound has stopped. The button is called inactive button, and it is an image button. How do tell the compiler set the new image if the sound is not playing?

[Code snippet because stack won't let me post the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU4tw.png)

Comment: You **can** post the code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions seems very similar to one posted at the link below. Id say to give this solution a try.

[Android: Change button text after MediaPlayer audio ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520608/android-change-button-text-after-mediaplayer-audio-ends)

Essentially if you use the MediaPlayer class you can use the OnCompletionListener to trigger the button change.